# Children as a varible adding class/ changing css jQuery

Tags: jquery

Hi Am adding an opacity change on hover with Jquery. This works individually but when I create multiple parent divs with the class; hover-reveal-image. The second does not work. I need to then add this and only target the children. I tried this, but it didn't work.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        firstImage = jQuery(".hover-reveal-image .fusion-imageframe:eq(0)");
        secondImage = jQuery(".hover-reveal-image .fusion-imageframe:eq(1)");
        jQuery(secondImage).addClass('reveal-image-2');
        jQuery(".hover-reveal-image").hover(
            function() {
                jQuery(secondImage).addClass('reveal-image-visible');
                jQuery(firstImage).css('opacity','0');
            },function() {
                jQuery(secondImage).removeClass('reveal-image-visible');
                jQuery(firstImage).css('opacity','1');
            }
        );
    });
```

```css
.hover-reveal-image .fusion-imageframe {
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.reveal-image-2 {
  opacity: 0!important;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px!important;
  top: 0px;
  width: calc(100% - 14.25%)!important;
}

.reveal-image-visible {
  opacity: 1!important;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hover-reveal-image">
  <div class="fusion-imageframe">
     <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532781-03e79bf5bec2?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=668&q=80" width="100px" height="50px">
  </div>
  <div class="fusion-imageframe">
     <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642634367-d91a135587b5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80" width="100px" height="50px">
   </div>
</div>

<div class="hover-reveal-image">
  <div class="fusion-imageframe">
     <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532781-03e79bf5bec2?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=668&q=80" width="100px" height="50px">
  </div>
  <div class="fusion-imageframe">
     <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642634367-d91a135587b5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80" width="100px" height="50px">
   </div>
</div>
```

This is what I tried

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        firstImage = jQuery(".hover-reveal-image .fusion-imageframe:eq(0)");
        secondImage = jQuery(".hover-reveal-image .fusion-imageframe:eq(1)");
        jQuery(secondImage).addClass('reveal-image-2');
        jQuery(".hover-reveal-image").hover(
            function() {
                jQuery(this).children(".fusion-imageframe:eq(1)").addClass('reveal-image-visible');
                jQuery(this).children(".fusion-imageframe:eq(0)").css('opacity','0');
            },function() {
                jQuery(this).children(".fusion-imageframe:eq(1)").removeClass('reveal-image-visible');
                jQuery(this).children(".fusion-imageframe:eq(0)").css('opacity','1');
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Off topic: Note that `:eq()` selector is deprecated.  https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close, i changed some small things and i think this is what the result should be according to the description.

I was missing some css on the parent for the absolute children so i added that, and changed the jquery around to search for the correct div's inside the `.hover-reveal-image` that was being hovered

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".hover-reveal-image").hover(
            function() {
                $(this).find(".fusion-imageframe").not(".reveal-image-2").css('opacity','0');
                $(this).find(".reveal-image-2").addClass('reveal-image-visible');
            },function() {
                $(this).find(".reveal-image-2").removeClass('reveal-image-visible');
                $(this).find(".fusion-imageframe").not(".reveal-image-2").css('opacity','1');
            }
        );
    });
```

```css
.hover-reveal-image .fusion-imageframe {
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  /* setting height and with the same as the images */
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}
/* position relative for parents of absolute children */
.hover-reveal-image {
position: relative;
}

.reveal-image-2 {
  opacity: 0!important;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px!important;
  top: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: calc(100% - 14.25%)!important;
}

.reveal-image-visible {
  opacity: 1!important;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hover-reveal-image">
  <div class="fusion-imageframe">
     <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532781-03e79bf5bec2?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=668&q=80" width="100px" height="50px">
  </div>
  <div class="fusion-imageframe reveal-image-2">
     <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642634367-d91a135587b5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80" width="100px" height="50px">
   </div>
</div>

<div class="hover-reveal-image">
  <div class="fusion-imageframe">
     <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532781-03e79bf5bec2?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=668&q=80" width="100px" height="50px">
  </div>
  <div class="fusion-imageframe reveal-image-2">
     <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642634367-d91a135587b5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80" width="100px" height="50px">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestion, I edited what you advised and this worked best for me:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".hover-reveal-image .fusion-imageframe").odd().addClass('reveal-image-2');
        jQuery(".hover-reveal-image").hover(
             function() {
                jQuery(this).find(".fusion-imageframe").not(".reveal-image-2").css('opacity','0');
                jQuery(this).find(".reveal-image-2").addClass('reveal-image-visible');
            },function() {
                jQuery(this).find(".reveal-image-2").removeClass('reveal-image-visible');
                jQuery(this).find(".fusion-imageframe").not(".reveal-image-2").css('opacity','1');
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```